# On submit, do animation and wait to complete, then submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsubmit

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('.thing').fadeOut('slow', function() {

        $('form').submit();

    });

});
```

Do you see the dilemma here? I'm trying to fade out a div when a form is submitted, then wait for the animation to complete, then actually submit the form.

But once I prevent the default behavior, animate the div, then try submit the form, the script loops back around, hits `preventDefault()` and avoids submitting again.

I would use `onClick` for the initial event, but I want pressing the enter key to work as well. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the submit binding after it's been fired.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').off();
    $('.thing').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer this solution because it is a little more explicit/obvious at a glance when I come back to this code later what is happening, rather than using the word "bind," even though that's technically what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('form').bind('submit' , function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $('.thing').fadeOut('slow', function() {
   $('form').unbind();
  });
});
```

Bind and then unbind